# Visual Studio: cannot access resources from code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources

I added several files (HTML, CSS, etc.) as resources to my Visual Studio project. According to MSDN, I should be able to access these resources via

```
MyProjectName.Properties.Resources.Filename
```

Unfortunately, IntelliSense doesn't even know the Properties property behind MyProjectName. If I type "MyProjectName.", IntelliSense offers me several things but no properties. I already built the project, but nothing changed.

If this is important: that project is not the main/startup project of my Visual Studio solution.

Comment: You have added the resources to your main project (exe) and then trying to read them from another project (dll)?

Comment: no, I added them to another project, not the main project. But I only need those resources in that other project

Comment: neither nor. It's a library project

Comment: I had a similar issue and I solved it doing [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46853218/5733851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the file as a resource from its properties as:

```
BuildAction=Compile
```

Comment: Oh, I first thought you mean the specific resource files. Did you mean the resource.designer.cs instead? This is the point, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You need to add them here:

1. Project menu
2. MyProjectName Properties
3. Resources tab
4. "Click here to create resources" (if necessary)
5. Select Files menu
6. Add Resource

Now you can access them using `MyProjectName.Properties.Resources.Filename`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [MSDN Forum link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/baffedf2-95ec-44c4-9b02-0d1fb5f34d31). What I take from it is make sure your resources are [added as resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and that the namespace's match.

Comment: the namespace of the properties file is "Projectname.Converter.Properties" and the namespace of the class in which I want to use the resource is "Projectname.Converter.XY". does that mean I only can use one single namespace in a project if I want to use resources? Cannot imagine that

Comment: @alapeno The accepted answer of the MSDN Forum link seems to state that, though he had an issue with his Base Namespace being different. All I can say is try changing it to see if it is the issue. Just trying to give you some ideas

Comment: Thanks Mark, I got that answer of the MSDN forum wrong. As you said, the basenamespace was the issue there, but not in my case. My Resource.Designer.cs build action was set to "embedded resource" instead of compile, maybe that was the problem, it finally works

Comment: @alapeno I am glad. The embedded resource's being the issue kind of makes sense since the files are being compiled into the `dll` or `exe`.

Comment: Solved my problem. Not allowing devs to access their resources from R-clicking on resources and adding the files is very strange to say the least and has probably caused a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they're marked as resources?  Right click and check their properties.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little confusing that there is a folder in Visual Studio called Propertieson the same level as Resourcesbut which is bypassed altogether.

So while the path in your code may go via `Solution_name.Properties.Resources.yourFile.png` this does not reflect in the folders used in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio, as there you find the image then directly under **Solution_name\Resources\yourFile.png**.

And just adding a file and moving the resource with the mouse won't make Visual Studio find this file as Resource in your code. So you must go through menu *Project*, *Properties* (lowest entry) ? or click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, Highlight Resources.

Now click on the ***Drill-down-Arrow of Add Resource*** rather than just on the main area of the button. Doing that would open the dialog window for **Add New Resource**, but actually you want to click ***Add Existing File***. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is contrary what answer said but on VS2013, I had to set BuildAction=Resource

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else perhaps check the Resources.Designer file?

I found a discrepancy on this line

```
 System.Resources.ResourceManager("DemoApp.Properties.Resources", ...
```

I had changed the project name to Demo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will it help or not but all I had to do is creating a new form and adding an icon to picturebox. Somehow that solved the problem.