# Accessing Visual Studio Resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can't reference the images in my VS resources directory.

Based on what I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368025/visual-studio-cannot-access-resources-from-code) I do it like this:

> MyProject.Properties.Resources.Append_16x16

And then I set the build action to "Compile".

But then this line fails at compile time:

```
this._appendToolStripButton.ImageTransparentColor = MyProject.Properties.Resources.Append_16x16;
```

The only files that I can access (they show up in IntelliSense) are the ones I didn't copy from another project.

Strange.

Comment: `are the ones I didn't copy from another project.`  How did you add these resources to the project?

Comment: @LarsTech: I inherited these files via TFS, so I can't say :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to reference images this way you have to R-click on that project's properties directory in the solution explorer, clicking "Open", click on the "resource" tab, and then hit "Add Resource".

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

This design of VS where you can add these files by R-clicking the Resources directory in the solution explorer, but the path reference won't work is poor.