# Can't see Resources namespaces in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Everything was fine but suddenly Resources stopped working.
I have ASP.NET MVC5 Application.

All i see is message:

> Error    3: The type or namespace name 'User' does not exist
>        in the namespace 'MyProject.Resources' (are you missing
>        an assembly reference?)

But, this problem is **only** in **.cs** files! In **Views** everything is OK!
All I see for example in some controller is **Resources.App_LocalResources** but this is empty namespace. In **.cshtml** file I see **all** my resources!
It looks like some problem with Visual Studio, because it happend suddenly. Earlier everything was fine.
Any ideas?

I have already restarted Visual Studio many times, I have resterd even computer. But nothing's changed.

**EDIT:**

Problem solved.
I have replaced .csproj of my Resources project to older version. I had to add again few files but now everything's OK.
So it was damaged project file.

Comment: Are your resources' access modifiers set to public ?

Comment: Is there any chance to rename your User.resx

Comment: I can rename it. But it's not a problem. I have many Resources files. I wrote "User" as example, but there is many files. In Views everything is OK.

I have 3 projects in my solution
1. Database 'core'
2. Resources
3. My web app.

And I see resources ONLY in My web app in .cshtml files! (And they work of course).

Comment: Hmm, i think there is a problem on building your solution. Think you have already cleaned all your solution and rebuilt it. Have u tried giving a full path to your resources like MyProject.Resources.User.NAME ?

Comment: Of course... I did it many times. I am sure that this is problem with Visual Studio, not in code. Maybe somehow my project is damaged, i don't know...
EDIT: Yes, I've tried. Nothings' changed.

Comment: Hmm your csproj may be damaged as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do "unload project" when right clicking on the Core/database project. Right click on the project file again selecting "edit". Now you should be able to manually edit the csproj file.
Try adding the missing references, or editing them if they are pointing to the output folder of your build

Comment: Yes, it was damaged .csproj file. 
I've replaced it to older version, add again few files and everything work now.

Comment: Please, see my new answer below

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved it doing the following steps:

1. Changing the [Resource Propertie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXscI.png) 'Custom Tool' to 'PublicResXFileCodeGenerator'.
2. After changing this propertie, the Resource Class was automaticaly updated as follows: [Class Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIIAk.png).

After these steps I was able to make the correct reference to the resource file.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that!
Project is crashing after adding exactly 10 resources files!

As long as there is max 9 files - it works. I add 10th file and errors appear! I remove this file, and everything is OK again!

How can this happen?!

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens in your solution. This might be obvious to you but did you check the validity of your files and did you try with only adding one file that you _know_ works multiple times? If you did try these things i'm not sure why you solution behaves like it does. Just out of interest: What kind of files are you adding to the resource files? Xml? png?

Comment: It was very terrible day. But after restart computer again, project works correctly now. 
No matter what kind of file I added to project, it was crashing after 10th file (But I was adding .resx files). It sounds funny, but it wasn't funny for me. So, to summarise - I think Visual Studio sometimes like to do strange things. Maybe it wanted me to let me go away from computer for a while and rest :)